# How to grab column values and paste them into horizontal rows?

Tags: mysql, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a table like this:

```
EID Code
--------
001 SCP
002 CSP
003 SCP
004 CSP
005 SCP
```

I want to change it to look like this:

```
EID SCP CSP
-----------
001  *
002      *
003  *  
004      *
005  *
```

How to write an Excel formula to get it done?

Seems we need to use index to have a subquery, but I failed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT EID,
    IF( CODE == 'SCP', '*', '') AS SCP,
    IF( CODE == 'CSP', '*', '') AS CSP
FROM yourTAble
ORDER by EID;
```